# Calculating probality based on descriptive data

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics

Maybe it is a basic question, **how can I calculate what is the probality the x>=2 based on this data:** (95% conf level)

```
Mean                5,954774
Standard Error      0,112709
Median              6
Mode                5
Standard Deviation  2,248529
Sample Variance     5,055884
Kurtosis            1,722383
Skewness            0,759457
Range               15
Minimum             1
Maximum             16
Sum                 2370
Count               398
Confidence Level(95,0%) 0,22158
```

**Edit**: clarifying my question: If I get another data point x from the same process, what is the probability that x≥2

Comment: There are two possible interpretations of your question: a) If you would get another data point $x$ from the same process, what is the probability that $x \geq 2$  OR b) Given the observed data, what is the probability that the mean value of all the data points is $\geq 2$ - could you clarify which is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your count is reasonably high, a good first answer is that it is the proportion of $x \geq 2$ in the data you observed so far.

Being more precise requires further assumptions on the way your data were generated. It is very useful to visualize your data (e.g. as a histogram) along with computing summary statistics as those alone can be misleading (see [Anscombe's quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet)). From the statistics you have shown it looks like your data are integers and are not approximately normally distributed (kurtosis and skewnes != 0). This precludes usage of many of the common tools which assume normal distributions.

To go further, you would need to determine which distribution models your data, which you can do from theory (e.g. no. of accesses to a website per hour would likely be Poisson distributed) or visually by looking at the histogram. Then you can estimate the parameters $\theta$ (or a confidence interval thereof) of the distribution from the data you have. The cumulative distribution function $F_{\theta}$ (accessible from most statistical software) then gives you directly $F_{\theta}(y) = Prob(x \leq y)$. Computing this probability for each of the interval bounds of the parameters will give you confidence for the probability.

Comment: Thanks Martin for your answer! Yes, that's my problem, what you wrote, my data is not normally distributed so I am not sure how to adjust the probability with the kurtosis (!=3) and skewnes. I thought there may be some easieser way.

Comment: @CsengerÁbrahám I am not sure what you mean by "adjust probability", but just looking at the proportion of an event in the data generally does not need any adjustment when you have a lot of observations. There is not much how we can help you further unless you provide more details about your data (what it represents + histogram or other visualisations).